# Given 20 persons, assuming no leap years, probability of 5 persons who are born on Independence day and 5 persons who are born on Columbus day?

Tags: probability

> There are 20 persons in a room. Assuming no leap years, the probability that there are 5 persons who are born on Independence day and 5 persons who are born on Columbus day?

Comment: We would also need to assume that each day of the calendar is equally likely and that the birth dates of each person is independently chosen.  Once having done this, it is a straightforward application of the [multinomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution).

Answer (score 0):

You know the probability of a person being born on Independence day or Columbus day is $\frac{1}{365}$. A person has a $\frac{363}{365}$ chance of being born on any other day. Let $X_1, X_2, X_3$ be the number of people born on Independence Day, Columbus day and any other day respectively. Using multinomial distribution, then we have

$$P(X_1=5, X_2=5, X_3=10)=\frac{20!}{5!5!(10)!}(\frac{1}{365})^5(\frac{1}{365})^5(\frac{363}{365})^{10}$$